# Bind to list of object with known types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have following wrapping classes used as view model property:

```
public abstract class MultipleFormsModel
{
    public class FormModel
    {
        public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
        public object Model { get; set; }
    }
    public int FormSelector { get; set; }
    public List<FormModel> Models { get; set; }
}
public class MultipleFormsModel<T1, T2> : MultipleFormsModel
{
    public MultipleFormsModel() {}
    public MultipleFormsModel(int val1, T1 model1, int val2, T2 model2)
    {
        Models.Add(new FormModel() { SelectedValue = val1, Model = model1 });
        Models.Add(new FormModel() { SelectedValue = val2, Model = model2 });
    }
}
```

Then I have some model, which uses the above mentioned wrapping classes.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    //... other properties
    public MultipleFormsModel<SomeModel1, SomeModel2> MultipleModels { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        MultipleModels = new MultipleFormsModel<SomeModel1, SomeModel2>(0, new SomeModel1(), 1, new SomeModel2());
    }
}
```

This model is passed to the view and displayed using `@Html.EditorForModel()` call it is displayed. Of course there are some templates for MultipleFormsModel, and FormModel, which draws just the important parts, but that is not interesting for the topic.
The problem happens when the form is posted back. The values are not bound into the model `ViewModel`. (And yes, the name and ids of the inputs in the forms are correct)

My guess is that it is caused, because the default model binder treat the `ViewModel.Models[x].Model` as type `object`, which has no property. But as you may see it is created as concrete type (either `SomeModel1` or `SomeModel2`).
I read this [paper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) and I suspect the cause is hidden somewhere in the following text:

> Next, the AbstractModelBinder uses the concrete type name to generate a new set of metadata that describes the details of the concrete class. AbstractModelBinder uses this new metadata to replace the existing ModelMetadata property that described the initial abstract model type, effectively causing the model binder to forget that it was ever bound to a non-concrete type to begin with.

The problem here is, that I have no idea where to start. What I need is to make DefaultModelBinder treat the properties types as theirs **real**, not declared types - is it even possible?

Comment: I don't think the default model binder can do this, for exactly the reason you say.  The declared static type is `object`.  Maybe `FormModel` can be made generic?  Then there would at least be more specific static typing behind it, which *might* work (or at least come closer to working).

Comment: You would have to create a custom model binder. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) may help.

Comment: @David - I have thought of this idea, but then I don't know how to make list of Models (list of different object types is again the list of `object`). The idea behind this wrapper is to have multiple childs with more and more generic types, and it is used to have multiple subforms switchable by one switch (radio) where any of the radio brings in (and hide others) different form.

Comment: @Zoka: It sounds like you're essentially creating a custom type system for your application, which would involve a custom model binder in that case.

Comment: @Stephen - Yes, I guess I must create the custom model binder. But, I'm very lazy, and don't want to reinvent the wheel, and especially do not want to implement some already implemented functionality. My guess is that I need to change the ModelMetadata for `ViewModel.Models[x].Model`, but have no idea how :-(